# Cannot rewrite function in R

Tags: r

I toyed around a bit with R, and I'm curious to learn why this does not work:

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript

# initializes function
s <- function() {
    return(0);
};

# run function to see it's there (should return 0)
s();

while (s() != 12) {

    # print function to see its contents
    print(s);

    # rewrite function, hopefully it will return 12 now
    s <- paste("function() {",
               "return(",
               sample(1:100,1),
               "+",
               sample(1:100,1),
               ")",
               "}"
    )
}

print(solve);
```

The output is:

```
dooh@dooh:~$ '/home/dooh/Desktop/solve.R/solve.R' 
[1] 0
function () 
{
    return(0)
}
Error: could not find function "s"
Execution halted
```

Somehow, `s` was turned into a string, and doesn't live anymore as a function - and so, the evaluation after `while` will never return 12. How can I coerce a string into a function?

Comment: This sounds like an x-y problem to me. What is the larger problem you're trying to solve? To answer the question: your loop ends because you try to execute `s()`. As `s` is a string in the second iteration, function `s` cannot be found and execution halts.

Comment: Well gosh -- you just replaced your function `s` with a text string.   You can't just magically make that be a function again.   YOu'll need to read some R-intro  documents.   ahh, ninja'd by @Heroka

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve? Learning how to make R rewrite functions, and stopping as soon as the function returns the right value. I'm no professional at all, so bear with me.

Comment: The `body` function allows you to change the body of a function. For instance, you can replace the `s<-...` line with `body(s)<-expression(sample(1:100,1)+sample(1:100,1))`. However, it is rather unusual that one wants to change the body of a function, and it's definitely not recommended for someone who is moving their first steps in R. You should learn to walk before trying to run.

Comment: you can also just do `s <- eval(parse(text = s))` after `s <- paste...` It didn't work because you turned s into a character string, so when the while loop starts again and tries `s()`, you get an error. same as if you had done `something()` `Error: could not find function "something"
`

Comment: In addition to the first comment, which correctly points out that you are trying to solve the wrong problem (or rather, trying to solve a problem in fundamentally the wrong way, i.e. via redefining a function), there’s also the issue that your code looks more like C than R. for starters, don’t use semicolons, they are completely unnecessary in your code. So is the `return`.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, and I'll try out the solution given by rawr. I'm actually using R since more than five years to do my scientific work (in addition to solving Project Euler problems in R), so I'm by far not a beginner. But there are these things like "How can I program a program that programs a program that solves some stupid questions" which I want to learn more about.

Comment: Thanks, Konrad, but at the same time I'm also learning a bit of C++, and the practices I learn there I sometimes carry over to R. So there is the explicit return() because I want to easily see what is returned. Also the semicolons. And I'm actually writing function prototypes and a "main" function... in R.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
s <- function() {
        return(0);
};

# run function to see it's there (should return 0)
s();

while (s() != 12) {

        # print function to see its contents
        print(s);

        # rewrite function, hopefully it will return 12 now
        s <- as.function(alist(sample(1:100,1)+sample(1:100,1)))

        }
```

Comment: This solution assigns the same function body to s all the time - it always contains the two sample() statements. What I want to achieve is that s <- function() {3 + 4} once, then s <- function() {39 + 23}, then something else - until s() equals 12.